# angular form validation - set required by code (not working)

Tags: angularjs

```
    if(currentAdmin.target =='new')
    {
        $('#btnDel').hide();
        //Not working !!!
        $('#inputPassword1').attr("ng-required","true");
        $('#inputPassword2').attr("ng-required","true");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#btnDel').show();
        $('#inputPassword1').attr("ng-required","true");
        $('#inputPassword2').attr("ng-required","true");
    }
```

Well, basically I want to place the ng-required based on the condition. I made a trial using the required (without ng) and it does not works as well.

I inspected the element and injected the required and ng-required into the html and it's not works.
This will always be ignored after rendered. I need to do such thing like "Validator, refresh because it's different now"

any clue ?

Comment: its not angular :), see this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/81jgWv

Comment: if you want to learn angular, remove jQuery library from page. Start learning how to manage the DOM from your data models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I myself hate the kind of answer I am about to give, I feel it is appropriate in this situation: This is not the way to write if using angular...

So what should you do?

place the ng-required in the html code and set the value of the attribute to a bound variable that you set depending on your condition.

Example:

index.html

```
<form ng-controller="formController">
  <input type="password" ng-required="isAdmin">
  <input type="password" ng-required="!isAdmin">
</form>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('formController', function($scope){
  $scope.isAdmin=false;
  if(currentAdmin.target == 'new'){
    $scope.isAdmin=true;
  }
});
```

Not complete code, but hopefully you still understand what I mean.

Comment: <input ng-required="currentAdmin.target=='new'"